# How to predict for each row in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to predict for each row in the dataframe by iterating through the rows.

I have tried the solution mentioned in [Row-wise prediction over Pandas dataframe by passing sklearn.predict to df.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772060/row-wise-prediction-over-pandas-dataframe-by-passing-sklearn-predict-to-df-apply) but this is only for a single row.

Here's a snippet of what I've so far tried.

```
prediction = X_test.apply(lambda x: model.predict([x])[0],axis=1)
predictions = [round(value) for value in prediction]

accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions)
print("Test Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

I want to be able to loop this code for all present rows.

Comment: did you try `prediction  = model.predict(X_test)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I want to save the prediction for each row. Using model.predict(X_test) won't help with that

Comment: for a general `sklearn` model, `model.predict(X_test)` does give prediction for each row.

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry for being unclear, but my end goal is to predict time taken for prediction of each row. I'm not sure how to do that simply with model.predict(X_test)

Comment: What you wrote there is for *all* rows in `X_test`. What do you mean by *all present rows*?